# Almacenar en variable php campo option select

Tags: mysql, html5, php7

tengo un problema con mi código PHP. Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form class="ver__pedido" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <h4>Nuevo pedido:</h4>  
              <label for="cliente">Cliente:</label>
              <select id="cliente" name="cliente">
                <?php 
                $base = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=proyecto_fp", "root", "");
                $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
                //creamos una variable para almacenar la consulta
                $sql="SELECT user FROM clientes";
                $clientes=$base->prepare($sql);
                $clientes->execute();
                while ($devuelve=$clientes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    extract($devuelve);
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php $user; ?>"> <?php echo $user;?></option><br><?php
                }
                ?>
              </select>
              <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
              <input type="date" name="fecha"><br>
              <label for="hora">Hora:</label>
              <input type="time" name="hora"><br>
              <button type="submit" name="nuevo">Siguiente</button>
              </form>
```

Bien, el option devuelve una lista de usuarios de la cual yo necesito seleccionar uno, darle una fecha y una hora y que se me almacene en otra tabla, pero no consigo que me almacene nada en la variable $cliente, el código que se ejecuta despues de pulsar el boton es el siguiente:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['nuevo'])) {
    $cliente=$_POST['cliente'];
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
    $hora=$_POST['hora'];
 try {
        //creamos el nuevo ojeto $base que es la conexion de la clase PDO
        $base = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=proyecto_fp", "root", "");
        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
        $sql="INSERT INTO pedidos (user, fecha, hora) VALUES( :user, :fecha, :hora)";
        $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->execute(array(
            ":user"=>$cliente,
            ":fecha"=>$fecha,
            ":hora"=>$hora
        ));
        

        if ($resultado) {
            echo "Pedido Realizado";
        }else{echo "problemas";}

           

        $resultado->closeCursor();
   
    } catch (Exception $e) {
     
    } finally {
        $base=null;
    }
}
```

he probado de ejecutar un echo despues de almacenar las variables y fecha y hora responden, pero cliente no devuelve nada. Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda. Muchas gracias!